# Execute a default .py file in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm doing a Python project in Eclipse with PyDev. I have a "main" file and some "class" files. I primarily work in the classes, but I need to execute the code via the main file.

At the moment I need to either switch to the main file, or use the drop down menu of the run/debug-button to execute the main file. Pressing the button or using F11, just runs the class file (which is useless)

Is there a way to let PyDev always run a specific file in a project, or perhaps always run the last  file executed (which probably will be the best solution).

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Surely (relaunching the last launch was actually the default in in Eclipse 3.2, never understood why they changed that)...

You can have that back in the preferences at: **window > preferences > Run/Debug > Launching** and set the Launch Operation to **Always launch the previously launched application**.

So, **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>** will relaunch the last launch and **<kbd>F11</kbd>** will debug the last launch...

And to launch the file initially you may:

- Use a shortcut: **<kbd>F9</kbd>** to run the current opened file
- Go to the menu: **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>** + The number of the Run you wish (It can be Python, Jython, unit-test, etc).
- If you are using unit-tests, you could use: **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>** to run the unit-tests from the current module (and even selecting which tests should be run).
- Relaunch some other launch you did previously: **<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>** and choose a previous launch to relaunch.
- You may also launch in unit-test mode all files beneath a folder by right clicking the folder > run as > Python unit-test

(reference: http://pydev.org/manual_101_run.html)

And if you use unit-tests, you may also want to take a look at: [Continuous unit testing with Pydev (Python and Eclipse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015581/continuous-unit-testing-with-pydev-python-and-eclipse)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me with Pydev and Eclipse 2020-06 (4.16.0).